# onkeyup function removed table header

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a simple search function that filter the table. It works fine.
However, it hides the header too. How can I omit the header from the search? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PHP/HTML:

```
    //Create a table to display the output 
    echo '<input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names..">';
    echo '<div class="table-responsive">';
    echo '<table id="myTable"><tr bgcolor="#cccccc"><td>Name</td><td>E-Mail Address</td><td>Office Phone</td><td>Mobile</td></tr>';

    //Populate the table from LDAP
    echo "<tr><td>".$LDAP_FirstName." " .$LDAP_LastName."</td><td><a class='one' href='mailto:" .$LDAP_InternetAddress. "'>" .$LDAP_InternetAddress."</td><td>".$LDAP_OfficePhone."</td><td>".$LDAP_CellPhone."</td><tr>";
    echo("</table>");
    echo("</div>");
```

Script:

```
function myFunction() {
 // Declare variables 
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
   input = document.getElementById("myInput");
   filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
   table = document.getElementById("myTable");
   tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

 // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
   td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
    tr[i].style.display = "";
  } else {
    tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
    } 
  }
}
```

Comment: maybe simply replace for-loop with `for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++)`

Comment: *Smashes hand in face. Goes back to noobville... Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your header would be the first element, so skip the first element in your for-loop

```
for (i = 1; i < tr.length; i++) //replace 0 with 1
```